# Error pushing to proper Heroku Web App

Tags: git, heroku

Somewhere along the way here I copied a node app and it's still associated with an old git repository/heroku app.

When I try to create a new heroku app and push to heroku i get the following error:

```
!  No such app as young-journey-xxxx

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However I don't want to push to `young-journey-xxxx`.  I want to push to 'SOMENAME' which i just created using:

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

how do i tell node/git to use SOMENAME on Heroku now?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add your heroku app as a remote.

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#git_remotes_and_heroku

Comment: yeah so git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:appname.git works but only AFTER removing the old association with `it remote rm heroku`.  Thanks.